# No instance of overloaded function matches the argument list, argument types are: (std::ifstream, std::string, char)

Tags: c++, getline

I try to run the program to load the txt file into the linked list but got stuck at the "getline" error. In the **readLine** function, i try to get the content in the txt file but it did not allow me. Does anyone know how to fix this? I have tried to search the problem and read answers about it but i still don't know how to fi the problem. Thanks in advance.

> Linkedlist.h

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
Node* Node::createNode(Item newData)
{
    Node* point = new Node;
        if (point == nullptr)
        {
            cout << "Failed." << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        point->data = newData;
        point->setNext(nullptr);
        return point;
}

void LinkedList::createList(LinkedList& list)
{
    list.head = nullptr;
    list.tail = nullptr;
}
void LinkedList::insertHead(LinkedList& list, Node* point)
{
    if (list.head == nullptr)
    {
        list.head = list.tail = point;
    }
    else
    {
        point->setNext(head);
        list.head = point;
    }
}
void LinkedList::appenTail(LinkedList& list, Node* point)
{
    if (list.head == nullptr)
    {
        list.head = point;
        list.tail = point;
    }
    else
    {
        list.tail->setNext(point);
        list.tail = point;
    }
}
void LinkedList::readLine(ifstream& file, Item& item)
{
    **getline(file, item.getItemId(), ',');
    getline(file, item.getTitle(), ',');
    getline(file, item.getLoan(), ',');
    getline(file, item.getCopy(), ',');
    getline(file, item.getFee(), ',');
    getline(file, item.getGenre(), ',');**
}

void LinkedList::readAllFile(ifstream& file, LinkedList& list)
{
    while (!file.eof())
    {
        Node* point = new Node;
        Item item;
        Node node;
        readLine(file, item);
        point = node.createNode(item);
        appenTail(list, point);
    }
}

void LinkedList::printOneLine(Item item)
{
    cout << item.getItemId() << ',' << item.getTitle() << ',' << item.getLoan() << ',' << item.getCopy() << ',' << item.getFee() << ',' << item.getGenre();
}

void LinkedList::printAll(LinkedList list)
{
    for (Node* point = list.head; point != NULL; point = point->getNext())
    {
        printOneLine(point->getData());
    }
}
```

> Item.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Item
{
protected:
    string itemId, title, type, loan, num_copy, fee, genre;
public:
    Item() {}
    Item(string itemId, string title, string type, string loan, string num_copy, string fee, string genre)
        : itemId(itemId), title(title), type(type), loan(loan), num_copy(num_copy), fee(fee), genre(genre)
    {}
    ~Item() {}
    string getItemId() { return this->itemId; }
    string getTitle() { return this->title; }
    string getType() { return this->type; }
    string getLoan() { return this->loan; }
    string getCopy() { return this->num_copy; }
    string getFee() { return this->fee; }
    string getGenre() { return this->genre; }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your accessors don't return string&, but a new copy of a string that cannot be passed as a string&.

```
    string& getItemId() { return itemId; }
    string& getTitle() { return title; }
    string& getType() { return type; }
    string& getLoan() { return loan; }
    string& getCopy() { return num_copy; }
    string& getFee() { return fee; }
    string& getGenre() { return genre; }
```

On top of that, don't use `using namespace std`, use `std::move` in your constructor, don't use `exit` but throw an exception...

Comment: Have you tried your answer? That's the error, you cannot use a rvalue as an lvalue.

Comment: Thanks very much, sir. You help me fix my problem. But i don't quite understand what you said, can u recommend me some books or website to read about it?

Comment: You can have a look at SO unofficial list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still have a long way to go.